# How to allow auto-generated and user-generated unique identities in same field

Tags: sql, sql-server

My `Customers` table currently has a unique identity field called `CustomerCode`.

When a new customer is added to the table, I want the `CustomerCode` field to auto-generate an identity. This is simple enough to achieve.

However a user may already have a list of customers with unique identities from a previous application or manual record keeping system. They want to import these customers into this new table and retain their previous unique identities as their `CustomerCode`. CustomerCodes are alphanumeric e.g. CUS0157999Z

Is it beyond the role of the database to do this? Instead would I need a front-end application to do the auto-generating of a unique CustomerCode where one doesn't already exist?

The new system and old one have to run in tandem, so they'll be importing customers to the new `Customer` table on a daily basis.

Comment: `user-generated` and `unique` are usually mutually exclusive.

Comment: Are your customer codes alphanumeric?

Comment: Triggers can be used for that. If the CustomerCode is not given, then the trigger generates one.

Comment: Yes CustomerCode values will be alphanumeric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two different entities here - Customer ID and Customer Code. Usually Customer ID is generated automaticaly as sequential number and is used for referencing between data in tables. Usually Customer Code is generated according some rules and have meaningfull value, e.g. hierarchical or classificational, etc.

In your case better not mix them and use separately. So add another column, say `CustomerCodeImported`. In this case you have reference `CustomerCode` in your application as well as referense code to use when referencing into legacy application. This is more reliable in case you need to import existing customer - you can simply update existing record setting value for `CustomerCodeImported` column.

Answer (score 1):

The auto increment does not have to start at 1.  Import your client's data along with their unique customer codes.  After this set the auto increment to start at a value much later than that of the clients to distinguish between old and new.

For example, if the client has over 100k customers with ids from 100,000 to 150,000.  You can start the auto increment at 1,000,000.

This is of-course providing that the unique id generation methods are consistent across the old and the new system.